# swift Cannot convert value of type '[Liquor]' to expected argument type 'inout _'

Tags: ios, swift, casting, nscoding

I go through some similar questions but still cannot figure out why this happen.

```
var liquors = [Liquor]()

func loadSampleLiquors(){
    let photo1 = UIImage(named: "Chateau Lafite Rothschild 1993")
    let liquor1 = Liquor(name: "Chateau Lafite Rothschild", year: "1993", photo: photo1, rating: 7)
    liquors += [liquor1] // Here is the error happen     
}
```

the error messageis : Cannot convert value of type '[Liquor]' to expected argument type 'inout _'

This is probably because the "year" may be nil, but I go through my code that it should work well, I try to fix it using "if let liquors = xxx", but then there will be a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on the decode function, So I post all my code under here:

here is my liquor class:

```
var name: String
var year: String
var photo: UIImage?
var rating: Int

struct PropertyKey {
    static let nameKey = "name"
    static let yearKey = "year"
    static let photoKey = "photo"
    static let ratingKey = "rating"
}
```

I use NSCoding to store data:

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: PropertyKey.nameKey)
    aCoder.encode(year, forKey: PropertyKey.yearKey)
    aCoder.encode(photo, forKey: PropertyKey.photoKey)
    aCoder.encode(rating, forKey: PropertyKey.ratingKey)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.nameKey) as! String
    let year = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.yearKey) as! String
    let photo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.photoKey) as? UIImage
    let rating = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: PropertyKey.ratingKey)
    self.init(name: name, year:year, photo: photo, rating: rating)
}
```

Comment: Where's the declaration of `liquors`?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I just add it

Comment: I asked for the declaration of `liquors`, not `liquor`

Comment: my fault, change it @AlexanderMomchliov

Comment: BTW it's preferable to use an enumeration with no cases if you're just storing static constants.

Comment: Hmmm this is strange, I don't think it has anything with your coding/decoding. What happens if you use `append(_:)` instead of `+=`?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov not static, it's user data, this one is for a load sample.

Comment: I was talking about the `PropertyKey` struct, which seems to only be a contain static data

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov so when using append, it works, but when run the app, it will has EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on the decode year "let year = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.yearKey) as! String"

Comment: that force cast is failing, if i had to guess

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov yeah that's the wired thing, year is a variable I add secondly, the encode and decode works really fine before, and the year is just the same as the name variable. so what method you suggest I do?

Comment: Where is the decoding actually being triggered from?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Here: func loadLiquors() -> [Liquor]? {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: Liquor.ArchiveURL.path) as? [Liquor]
    }

Comment: So what does any of the code in the original question have to do with that?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov what do you mean? I should probably change the question to NScoding decode one?

Comment: I don't see any errors pertaining to `Cannot convert value of type '[Liquor]' to expected argument type 'inout _'1`

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov so I can't solve this...?

Comment: Your question is about the append not working. Your problem pertains to NSKeyedUnarchiver. Without information on that, we can't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the unwrap operator. Try this:

```
let liquor1 = Liquor(name: "Chateau Lafite Rothschild", year: "1993", photo: photo1, rating: 7)!
```

notice the "!" at the end

The reason you need to unwrap is because Liquor init can return nil, so it returns an optional. Thats the ? at the end of init

```
required convenience init?
```